# If $||T_n(x)|| \to 0$ pointwise, then $||T_n \circ S|| \to 0$ when $S$ is a compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Here $T_n, S$ are bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space $H$.

I have already proved the assertion when $S$ is an operator of finite rank.  And when $S$ is compact, one can find a finite rank operator $S'$ such that $||S-S'|| < \epsilon$.  This still does not seem to be enough to show that $\lim\limits_n ||T_n S|| = 0$.  We have $$||T_nS|| \leq ||T_nS - T_nS'|| + ||T_nS'|| \leq ||T_n|| \cdot ||S-S'|| + ||T_nS'||$$ where $||T_n S'||$ and $||S-S'||$ can both be made small.  The problem is that there is no guarantee that $||T_n||$ is bounded (I'm pretty sure).  Any help here?

I need to find a large enough $n$ to make $||T_n S'||$ small, and I also need $S'$ in the first place to get that $||S-S'||$ is small.

Comment: $\|T_n\|$ is indeed bounded. $\|T_nx\|\to 0$ implies that $\|T_nx\|$ is bounded for each $x$ and since you are working with Hilbert space, Uniform Boundedness Principle will imply that $\|T_n\|$ is bounded.

Comment: Ah of course!  Thank you!

Comment: And you need to make sure you know what a finite rank operator is.

Comment: :P (adding characters because I just wanted to write :P )

Comment: :P$\phantom{XXXXXXX}$.